Partitioning dataset by month into s3.to_parquet method
I have a dataframe. I wish to write into a bucket to be consulted later via Athena. The method s3.to_parquet offers the parameter partition_cols. However, I did not know how would I use the parameter to write the dataset in partition. In fact, I am a noobie in AWS or even creating dataset - most of my knowledge is consulting database. Can anyone help me?
PS: my database is updated daily (D-1) and partitioning seems to be a good practice.
I tried to write it down into several diferent .parquet files into a s3 bucket and then I used UNION ALL on Athena to form a new table, but that does not seem to be the right way of doing this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can consider partitioning by date column it will create a partition for each day.
